# How to display value of JSX function in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am quite new to jsx and while making my first Reactjs project today, I am facing this issue where I am unable to display the value of a function in the render method.

This is my parent page (Homescreen.jsx)

(I have commented on the sections where I felt that I have gone wrong)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Items from './Items'

class Render extends Component {
  render() { 
    return (
      <div>
        <Items number="This is the first item !" /> {/*This is where I am adding props to Items*/}

        <br>

        <Items number="This is the second item !" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
 
export default Render;
```

This is the child page (Items.jsx)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Items extends Component {
  // This is where I attempted to get the prop
  Items = (props) => {
    return (
      <p>{props.number}</p>
    )
  }
    
  render() { 
    return ( 
      <div className="form-group">
        {this.Items}            {/*This is where I tried to display the output of "number" prop*/}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
 
export default Items;
```

The end result is that the "Items" function has no output and I am getting an output which is the same as the output before adding the "Items" function.

Comment: Unrelated, but the code is hard to read; have you considered formatting it in a consistent, reasonable way?

Comment: The thing is, I am like super new to jsx, so I was scared that deleting any part of the code might make it harder for people to understand. As a result, I pasted the exact code from my IDE. I'll try to make it better in the future though !

Comment: "Formatting" != "deleting"

Comment: Your `Item` function takes a `props` param but you don't pass it one. If you're trying to use the `props` of the containing component do not shadow `Items` props, rather use `this.props` inside the `Item` function.

Comment: Thank you Dave for helping me. I have taken your suggestion and have reformatted my code, and also removed all the irrelevant lines. However, I am sorry if I sound super dumb, but I am not able to understand what you had suggested to me. Where do I put the `{this.props}` ?

Comment: Your function, `Item`, takes a `props` parameter. When you reference `Item` you (a) don't call the function, and (b) don't pass it any parameters. Since `Item` is a function, you must call it, e.g., `{this.Item()}`. Inside `Item` you can refer to the properties passed to `Items` with `{this.props.number}`. I would not name the function `Item`, however, rather something like `renderItem`--or just make it a wee functional component.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much Dave. I had searched for this online in many places, and I couldn't find it. Thank you so much for reformatting my code and taking the time out to answer. I don't know how to mark this as an answer, so I'll just upvote your answer. If there is anything else that I can do to mark your comment as an answer, or if I should answer it myself and then tag you, please tell me and I'll update it

Comment: You can just write an answer and accept it, although I suspect there are dupes of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `this.props.number` in render method. (you can access all props from `this.props`). Try the snippet, there are two ways shown here.

```js
class Items extends React.Component {
  Items2 = (props) => {
    return (
      <p>{props.number}</p>
    )
  }
  render() { 
    return ( 
      <div className="form-group">
        {this.props.number}
        {/* alternatively */}
        {this.Items2(this.props)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}


class Render extends React.Component {
  render() { 
    return (
      <div>
        <Items number="This is the first item !" />
        <br/>
        <Items number="This is the second item !" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Render />, document.getElementById("app"))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="app"></div>
```